# override template_name in listview subclass

Tags: django, templates, django-generic-views

I have a BookListView which displays all the books in my library. I have also a subclass of BookListView called BookSearchListView. I am trying to override the template by using the template_name variable. But this produces no effect.

views.py

```
class BookListView(generic.ListView):
   model=Book
   paginate_by=15



class BookSearchListView(BookListView):
   paginate_by=10
   template_name='booksearch_list.html'
   def get_queryset(self):
       pass
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^ksiazki/', views.BookListView.as_view(), name='books'),

url(r'^szukaj/', views.BookSearchListView.as_view(), name='search-list-view'),
```

I tried to override the template_name in views and in urls but in both cases it keeps book_list.html which is default template for BookListViews and not booksearch_list.html.

Comment: I also tried to override template_name in BookListView just to check whether I can but it also did not work. I do not have a clue why. I tried using both name and myapp/path/to/template.html - without any efect

Comment: Is your `booksearch_list.html` in the same folder as `book_list.html`?

Comment: yes. (however) I was wondering if the reason is that django displays first template it finds but I tried to use names that are alphabetically prior - with no success.

Comment: what is the structure of your app's `templates` folder?

Comment: ../appname/templates/appname/. I keep index.html and base html file (which is extended by templates) directly in 'templates' folder everything else is in templates/appname/.

Comment: Then you should have `template_name='appname/booksearch_list.html'` in your `BookSearchListView`

Comment: Yes it should. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `booksearch_list.html` template is in the *templates/appname/* folder then in your `BookSearchListView` the `template_name` should be:

```
template_name='appname/booksearch_list.html'
```